# How to LEFT ANTI join under some matching condition

Tags: pyspark

I have two tables - one is a core data with a pair of IDs (PC1 and P2) and some blob data (P3). The other is a blacklist data for PC1 in the former table. I will call the first table in_df and the second blacklist_df.

What I want to do is to remove rows from in_df long as in_df.PC1 == blacklist_df.P1 and in_df.P2 == black_list_df.B1. Here is a code snippet to show what I want to achieve more explicitly.

```
in_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,2,'A'],[2,1,'B'],[3,1,'C'], 
[4,11,'D'],[1,3,'D']],['PC1','P2','P3'])
in_df.show()

+---+---+---+
|PC1| P2| P3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  A|
|  2|  1|  B|
|  3|  1|  C|
|  4| 11|  D|
|  1|  3|  D|
+---+---+---+

blacklist_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,2],[2,1]],['P1','B1'])
blacklist_df.show()

+---+---+
| P1| B1|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  1|
+---+---+
```

In the end what I want to get is the followings:

```
+---+--+--+
|PC1|P2|P3|
+---+--+--+
|  1| 3| D|
|  3| 1| C|
|  4|11| D|
+---+--+--+
```

I tried LEFT_ANTI join but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Pass the join conditions as a list to the `join` function, and specify `how='left_anti'` as the join type:

```py
in_df.join(
    blacklist_df, 
    [in_df.PC1 == blacklist_df.P1, in_df.P2 == blacklist_df.B1], 
    how='left_anti'
).show()

+---+---+---+
|PC1| P2| P3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  D|
|  4| 11|  D|
|  3|  1|  C|
+---+---+---+
```