# Pyspark Dataframe - How to filter out records that are matching in another dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes in Spark.

**DF1:**

```
c1,c2
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

**DF2:**

```
c1,c2
d,4
e,5
a,6
```

I want to select all records from DF1 except the ones in DF2 where C1 columns are matching (value 'a' is in second dataframe so need to filter that record out from a first dataframe).
Result should be:
**DF3:**

```
c1,c2
b,2
c,3
```

Comment: You're looking for a `left-anti` join: `df1.join(df2, on="c1", how="leftanti")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to LEFT ANTI join under some matching condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343937/how-to-left-anti-join-under-some-matching-condition) and [What are the various join types in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990633/what-are-the-various-join-types-in-spark/45990634)

Comment: @Joe I have another solution which will be more performant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886077/spark-2-3-subtract-dataframes-but-preserve-duplicate-values-scala/59887116#59887116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exceptAll` as

```
df3 = df1.select("C1").exceptAll(df2.select("C1"))

result = df1.join(df3, df1.C1 == df3.C1).drop(df3.C1)
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know if this is possible to do when 2 or 3 columns need to match? (instead of 1 as in example)

Comment: `result = df1.join(df3, df1.C1 == df3.C1)` will add another extra column. What is the best way to remove it (not include it)?

Comment: Maybe add `left_semi` in the clause?

Comment: @Joe the best way to remove it is by calling `df.drop(df.columnName))`

Comment: but `result` dataframe has 2 columns with the same name (at 1st and last position).. So removing it by name is ambiguous.. Maybe I should rename it in `df3`..

Comment: Since the names are same you need to delete by a 'Column' not 'Column name'. So I advised to use dataframe.columnName not "columnName". Please see answer. I have updated with drop

Comment: When I did that `.drop(df3.C1)` -> it dropped first column with the same name (and not last)..